# Regular expression pattern for content within HTML tags

Tags: python, regex

I have coded simple Python script that connects to specific website and gets all the links 
there.

```
import urllib2
import re


request = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.securitytube.net/')
content = request.read()
match = re.findall(r'<a href=".\w+.\d+">.+</a>', content)
if match:
    for i in match:
        print i + "\n"

else:
    print 'Not Found!'
```

Result:

```
<a href="/video/3878"><img class="corner iradius20  ishadow33" width="100" heigh
t="75" src="http://videothumbs.securitytube.net.s3.amazonaws.com/3878.jpg"  alt=
"avatar" /></a>

<a href="/video/3878">NodeZero Linux Review</a>

<a href="/video/3877"><img class="corner iradius20  ishadow33" width="100" heigh
t="75" src="http://videothumbs.securitytube.net.s3.amazonaws.com/3877.jpg"  alt=
"avatar" /></a>

<a href="/video/3877">Post Attack Uploading Shell in Real Time</a>

<a href="/video/3867"><img class="corner iradius20  ishadow33" width="100" heigh
t="75" src="http://videothumbs.securitytube.net.s3.amazonaws.com/3867.jpg"  alt=
"avatar" /></a>

<a href="/video/3867">Using SQLMAP in Real Time (SQLinjection WEB)</a>

<a href="/video/3866"><img class="corner iradius20  ishadow33" width="100" heigh
t="75" src="http://videothumbs.securitytube.net.s3.amazonaws.com/3866.jpg"  alt=
"avatar" /></a>
....
...
...
```

I am trying to get those links with the understandable title, such as `<a href="/video/3867">Using SQLMAP in Real Time (SQLinjection WEB)</a>`.

My pattern is: `<a href=".\w+.\d+">.+</a>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/576139

Comment: For this simple case, try `[^<].*` or `\w.*`

Comment: Ok i got it(there is a module called BeautifulSoap which can helps me parse these html)but for the record, there is a way to get my pattern works well?

Comment: I prefer lxml.html over BeautifulSoup, cleaner API and works better

Comment: If regex is the issue here is your solution http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ heads and shoulders above the others i've tried..

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to use regexes instead of a proper parser, you can match `groups` and access them later on.

See http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

```
(...)
```

> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and
>   indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be
>   retrieved after a match has been performed

Try:

```
request = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.securitytube.net/')
content = request.read()
match = re.findall(r'<a href="(.*?)".*>(.*)</a>', content)
if match:
    for link, title in match:
        print "link %s -> %s" % (link, title)
```

this outputs:

```
link /video/3822 -> SecurityTube SpeakUp: Cloud Computing
link /video/3587 -> 
link /video/3587 -> Securitytube Speak Up: Antivirus Evasion attacks
link /video/3489 -> 
link /video/3489 -> SecurityTube SpeakUp: ThePirateBay LOSS
link /video/3375 -> 
link /video/3375 -> SecurityTube SpeakUp: .COM and .NET Domain Seizures
link /video/3130 -> 
link /video/3130 -> SecurityTube Speak Up: The MS12-020 Fiasco!
...etc
```

you can of course filter the links, so that only links with a matched title will be considered.
you will want to discard links starting with `#`, too... you see, a proper parser will give you better results.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever parse html with a regex.  ;-)

But in order to help you improve your regex-fu could be improved for future **non-HTML** work, there are two places where your regex is failing:

- `.\w+.\d+`  (this won't match the `/` in `/video/3877`.  Try `"[^"]+"
- `.+`, that is going to match as many of any character... try as few as possible: `.+?`

Comment: unless I'm missing something, shouldn't `.` match *anything* (including a `/`)?

Comment: @Chris, I was referring to the `<a href="` part - the `.*` is intended to match the contents of the tag, not the `<a href` part.